# writing array to Postgres using python's psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I have the following table in Postgres:

```
   Column   |            Type             | Modifiers 
------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 customer   | text                        | 
 feature    | character varying(255)      | 
 values     | character varying[]         | 
 updated_ts | timestamp without time zone |
```

And I'm trying to write the following pandas DataFrame

```
    customer     feature                       values           updated_ts
0     A             B                       [red, black]     2019-01-15 00:00:00 
1     A             B                       [blue, green]    2019-01-16 00:00:00
```

using the following code:

```
import psycopg2
...    
sio = BytesIO()
sio.write(df.to_csv(header=False, index=False, sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
sio.seek(0)
with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
    cursor.copy_from(file=sio, table=table, columns=df.columns, sep='\t', null='')
    connection.commit()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> DataError('malformed array literal: "[\'red\', \'black\']"\nDETAIL: 
>   "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.\nCONTEXT: 
>   COPY test_features_values, line 1, column values: "[\'red\',
>   \'black\']"\n',)

How do I write it correctly?

Comment: I would say you are trying to load a list onto a DB column, there are several reawsons why that is NOT a good idea,( look for fourth normal form). Quick fix, convert the array to a string, either by col = str(col), or [less bad] col = ','.join(col). Proper fix, revisit your data models and yoiur DB implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to convert the list to a set:

```
df['values'] = df['values'].apply(set)
```

for the insert to work. The reason is that PostgreSQL [expects arrays to be inserted using brace (`{}`) notation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), instead of bracket (`[]`) notation. When you convert from a list to a set, the `to_csv` method represents the set using the braces in the same configuration PostgreSQL expects (which was a pleasant surprise; I've seen other representations which it ends up being much hackier to convert).

The other thing I'll note is that in order to get it to work, I had to switch from `BytesIO` to `StringIO`, because `df.to_csv(...`) isn't a bytes-like object.

When I made those changes, the insert was successful:

```py
import csv
import pandas
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO 

# initialize connection
connection = psycopg2.connect('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

# create data
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'customer': ['A', 'A'],
    'feature': ['B', 'B'],
    'values': [['red', 'black'], ['blue', 'green']],
    'updated_ts': ['2019-01-15 00:00:00', '2019-01-16 00:00:00']
})
# cast list to set
df['values'] = df['values'].apply(set)

# write data to postgres
sio = StringIO()
sio.write(df.to_csv(header=False, index=False, sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
sio.seek(0)
with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
    cursor.copy_from(file=sio, table='test', columns=df.columns, sep='\t', null='')
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: But you should remember that you lose element repetitions and their order after converting list to set

Comment: Anybody every find a solution that preserves repeated elements and element order?

Comment: Haven't tested the postgres side of it, but something like `df['values'].apply(lambda x: "{" + ", ".join(x) + "}")` would probably do it. What you're doing is formatting the list to look like {...} instead of [...]. It's all written to string in the I/O stage anyway. Worth noting that this is a few years old now and the JSON support in Postgres has really come a long way so there might be an easier answer.